# Safari browser shrinking Cookies

Tags: http, cookies, safari

We are experiencing issues with Safari browsers (looks like all versions).

When Cookies reach some certain quota (not sure excaly who many bytes) some cookies that are supposed to go to our server with each request are gone.

Does anybody know what is the logic behind it and what may be the algorithm of Safari to delete cookies (oldest, biggest, alphabetically?).

If found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137305/safari-5-not-sending-all-cookies-back-to-the-server#) but it's pretty old and I was wondering if people are still experiencing this issue.

#### Edit

This issue seems to affect also latest version of Safari Desktop (up to Safari 11) and mobile versions.
Also seems that its related to AJAX requests.